# How to programmatically normalize a PCM audio sample on iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, normalization

I am recording a 16bit linear PCM file using `AVAudioRecorder`, saving it to a CAF file.

Now I want to normalize the audio I recorded.
I just cannot find ANY library, either Apple or 3rd party, that lets me do this for the iPhone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peak normalization takes this *general* form, which you'll have a few conversions, optimizations, and error checking to add for a 16 bit signal:

```
double* const buffer(...);
const size_t length(...);

double max(0);
// find the peak
for (size_t idx(0); idx < length; ++idx)
  max = std::max(max, buffer[idx]);
// process
double mul(1.0/max);
for (size_t idx(0); idx < length; ++idx)
  buffer[idx] *= mul;
```